# How to minimize my function for a specific parameter, and holding others constant

Tags: optimization, scipy, minimization

So I am trying to calculate the value of a parameter, beta, by minimizing the chi-square function. To do this, I'm using the scipy.optimize.minimize() function. I can't seem to get the code to do what I want. Is there a way to do this? I am open to other ways of approaching the problem.

For some background, the variables vr, rms and delta are both 1D tuples of the same length, and zeff, H and beta are parameters. I am trying to calculate an optimized beta value.

```
def chisq(beta,vr, delta,rvs,rms,zeff,H):
    c = -(H/(1+zeff))*(beta/3)
    model = c*np.multiply(rms,delta)
    q = (vr-model)**2
    p = model**-1
    ratio = np.multiply(p,q)
    chisq = np.sum(ratio)
    return chisq

initial_guess = 0.47663662075855323
res = opt.minimize(chisq,initial_guess,args =     (beta,delta,rvs,rms,zeff,H))
```

I usually get an error saying the dimensions of the function don't match the syntax for the minimize() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case beta is the optimization variable, so you don't need to pass it as an extra argument to the function chisq:

```
res = opt.minimize(chisq, x0=initial_guess, args=(vr, delta, rvs, rms, zeff, H))
```